# I can't capture the output of a procedure

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

When debugging a function that allows me to create a record, I can't get the output of the procedure. 'Output' never changes its value with which it is initialized ("").

```
    string Agregar(Empleado reg)
    {
        string mensaje = "";
        string output = "";

        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(cadena);

        try
        {
            cn.Open();

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pregunta02_3 @codEmp,@nom,@ape,@idpais,@email", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nom", reg.nomEmployee);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ape", reg.apeEmployee);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idpais", reg.idpais);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", reg.emailEmployee);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@codEmp", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          

            output = cmd.Parameters["@codEmp"].Value.ToString();
            mensaje = $"El codigo {output} ya existe";

            if (!output.Equals("0"))
                mensaje = $"Se ha registro el Empleado de codigo {output}";
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) 
        {
             mensaje = ex.Message; 
        }
        finally 
        {
             cn.Close(); 
        }

        return mensaje;
    }
```

The procedure returns a random employee code from a function that generates random numbers that are not in the table, if it already exists it returns 0.

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE  sp_pregunta02_3
    @codEmp int OUTPUT,
    @nom varchar(255),
    @ape varchar(255),
    @idpais char(3),
    @email varchar(255)
AS
BEGIN 
    SET @codEmp = dbo.fn_pregunta02();
    PRINT @codEmp

    IF @codEmp <> 0
    BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO tb_employee 
        VALUES (@codEmp, @nom, @ape, @idpais, @email)
    END
END
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_pregunta02_3, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@nom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reg.nomEmployee;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ape", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reg.apeEmployee;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@idpais", SqlDbType.Char).Value = reg.idpais;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = reg.emailEmployee;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@codEmp", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();          

        output = cmd.Parameters["@codEmp"].Value.ToString();
```

In stored procedure you must select the output

```
 CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE  sp_pregunta02_3
 @codEmp int output,
 @nom varchar(255),
 @ape varchar(255),
 @idpais char(3),
 @email varchar(255)
 as
BEGIN 
     SET @codEmp = dbo.fn_pregunta02();
     PRINT @codEmp
     IF @codEmp <> 0
     BEGIN 
        insert into tb_employee 
        values(@codEmp, @nom, @ape, @idpais, @email)
    END
   select @codEmp 
END
```

Comment: Get the same result

Comment: Is the output int or string? try to change it to varchar in stored procedure

Comment: change and neither SELECT CAST(@codEmp as varchar(10))

Comment: I updated my post, try code, also are you test the stored procedure and run it in sql server?

Comment: how to pass values? I no longer have AddWithValue

Comment: Sorry, see my updates

Comment: Is this fix your issue?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I still get the error

Comment: Try to run stored procedure in sql server to check if it give right data or not

Comment: yes, in sql it works DECLARE get int
EXEC sp_pregunta02_3 get output, 'franco','romero','001','franco@gmail.com'